# Update content without refreshing the page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I use CMS to create HTML pages with JSON inside a `script` tag. Single-file components use data from this JSON. I want to update page content when navigating a site without refreshing the page. All routes already exist, the CMS is responsible for everything.

As I understand it now, I need to make a request, get a HTML page, parse JSON from this page and update data and components, as well as change the insides of the `head` tag and update browser history.

Can I use Vue Router for this? Is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this, you can use Vue as plugin, like Jquery, you can receive data in JSON format from HTTP requests with a library like Axios. You cant'use VueRouter in this solution because you're not making an SPA.